# How to manage external dependencies of a Gradle Plugin

Tags: java, gradle-plugin, build-script, uberjar

- **Gradle Version**: *1.12/2.0 (restricted due to Org policies)*
- **JDK**: *1.8*

I have created a custom gradle plugin that performs some installation using code that has been defined in another sub-project of our source-code. The `build.gradle` for the plugin is

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':installlib', configuration: 'libConfig')
    compile project(path: ':tools', configuration: 'toolConfig')
}

jar {
    from {
        // LINE#1 source-code of plugin
        sourceSets.main.output  
        
        zip64 = true

        // LINE#2 dependencies
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
    baseName = 'myCustomPlugin'
    version = '1.0'
    destinationDir = new File(project.libDir)
}
```

The above plugin is consumed as follows - `consumer.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories { flatDir name: 'libs', dirs: System.env.CODESOURCE + '/lib/')
    dependencies {
        classpath: ':myCustomPlugin:1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'myCustomPlugin'

...
...
//rest of the items of this gradle
```

**Case-A**
If I run this, I hit `> Plugin with id 'myCustomPlugin' not found`.

*NOTE: I have `META-INF/gradle-plugins/myCustomPlugin.properties` created correctly with `implementation-class` pointing to my plugin code and this works fine if I don't get into creating the fat/uber-jar business and just include the `sourceSets.main.output` statement in my `jar` task. But since our entire project depends on file based artifacts, I am attempting to create a fat/uber-jar and that's where I start running into these issues.*

**Case-B**
If I move the LINE#2 above the LINE#1, which looks like -

```
from {
        // LINE#2 dependencies
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 

        // LINE#1 source-code of plugin
        sourceSets.main.output  

        zip64 = true
    }
```

If I run this, I hit `ClassNotFoundException` for one of the classes coming from the project `'installlib'`. I can see the `*.class` file in the uber jar created but even then the class loader complains about this class.

1. Could anyone provide some pointers on how to resolve this ? The uber/fat jar creation (or the way I am doing it) is not helping with the plugin-source-code and dependencies of the plugin.
2. If not a fat jar, could anyone provide some inputs on how to resolve the dependencies in the buildscript of the consuming gradle ?